# Ggrep only in the current directory

Tags: git, vim, vim-fugitive

I want to `:Ggrep` not from the git root directory but only in the directory the current file is open in vim.

I tried `:Ggrep search_key .`, but it still looks from the git root.

Even `:Git grep search_key .` does the same as `:Ggrep`

Answer (score 1):

`.` would expand to the current working directory iirc. Instead you should do something like this :

```
:Ggrep search_key <C-R>=expand('%:h')<CR><CR>
```

Comment: This is almost right, but it appears that `:Ggrep` treats relative directories as relative to the repository root, so you need to use the absolute directory with `expand('%:p:h')`.

Comment: It is relative the the current directory within vim.

Comment: No, I don't believe so. From [fugitive.vim:1206](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/90ee6fb5d255d14d9f12f2469f92ee50149f5b44/plugin/fugitive.vim#L1206) it looks to me that it's always relative to the repository root.